# React immutability helper - set new value at index in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way I can set value of array in specific index with React imutability helper ?

For example something like this:

```
   const newState = update(this.state , {
        open[8]:{$set: false}
    })
    this.setState(newState);
```

or do I have to deep clone that array using JSON and then set new value at specific index and then use react imutability helper to update state?

Comment: You could use `{ open: state.open.filter((value, index) => index != 8) }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your state has the following format:

```
{
  open: [
    true,
    false,
    true,
    ...
  ]
}
```

I believe this should work:

```
const newState = update(this.state , {
  open: {
    8: {$set: false}
  }
})
```